# JSON/RPC works fine for bitcoind but not for litecoind

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, json-rpc

I have managed to set up **bitcoind**, connect to its JSON/RPC API and run the **getinfo** command.

I followed exactly the same steps and configuration for litecoind (bitcoin.conf and litecoin.conf contain exactly the same settings) and set my client to connect to **litecoind** but I keep on hitting on a **HTTP 504** error.

Both bitcoind instances are in **testnet** mode and I succesfully connect to port 18332 for bitcoind and also connect to port 19333 for litecoind but this is as far as it gets, I can't seem to be able to get any reply from litecoind.

This is my configuration for both .conf files:

```
rpcuser = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
rpcpassword = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
testnet=1
daemon=1
rpcallowip=*
```

Any ideas?